# Print a digit using data from csv file

Tags: java, csv, machine-learning

I am trying to create a small machine learning system that prints a picture pattern from a csv file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PicturePrinter {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String line = "";
    int numData = 0;

    int[][] data = new int[20][65];

    public void readCSVFile(String csvFile) {

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

            String[] dataFromCSV = null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                dataFromCSV = line.split(",");
                for (String dataFromCSV1 : dataFromCSV) {
                    numData = Integer.parseInt(dataFromCSV1); //parse data
                    System.out.print(numData + ",");
                    for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
                        for (int col = 0; col < 65; col++) {
                            data[row][col] = numData; //store numData
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void print() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                if (numData == 0) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else if (numData > 6) {
                    System.out.print(" X ");
                } else if (numData < 6 || numData > 0) {
                    System.out.print(" x ");
                } else {
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PicturePrinter picturePrinter = new PicturePrinter();
    System.out.println("Reading data...");
    picturePrinter.readCSVFile("digits.csv");
    picturePrinter.print();
}
```

}

I have read the csv file and stored it in the array but then those i have to print it out in an 8x8. I tried looping through with if statements as you can see inside my `print()` method but it gives me like this.

```
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
```

It should like a handwritten 0 when it prints. The data looks like this.

[image]

How do I fix this? I was trying everything I can think of, is there something that I missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should like a 0 means what?

Comment: would you mind checking to see if the updated answer worked for you? I ran it locally and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `numData` is set to whatever was the last digit read in the `ReadCSVFile` method. Then the `print()` method comes in and runs a number of times with `numData` being equal to 9, the last number in your input.

Since 9 > 6; you get a bunch of X's.

Just add this line of code to your `print()` method under the second `for` loop definition:

`numData = data[row][col];`

In the future, take extra care when using class-level variables (like `numData` and `data` above). It's generally preferable to use local variables as input/output to functions which will help you avoid bugs like these and will also lead to cleaner more maintainable code.

*Edit: there was another issue in the ReadCSV file method where the all the values were read and `numData` was set to the last value. Then the double loop came in and wrote that same value (9) in each cell of your nested array*

*Edit: Here's what your new print() method should look like:*

```
    public void print() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                numData = data[row][col];
                if (numData == 0) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else if (numData > 6) {
                    System.out.print(" X ");
                } else if (numData < 6 || numData > 0) {
                    System.out.print(" x ");
                } else {
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

*here's what your new readCSVFile() method should look like*

```
        public void readCSVFile(String csvFile) {
            int currRow = 0;
            int currCol = 0;
            try {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

                String[] dataFromCSV = null;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    currRow++;
                    dataFromCSV = line.split(",");
                    for(String dataFromCSV1 : dataFromCSV) {
                        currCol++;
                        numData = Integer.parseInt(dataFromCSV1); //parse data
                        System.out.print(numData + ",");
                        data[currRow][currCol] = numData; //store numData
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

            } catch(IOException | NumberFormatException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: sorry for the late response.. I have just tried what you told me but it didn't work what I wanted. It prints the same thing.